how do i solve SUMIFS expects all arguments after position 3 to be in pairs in google sheet
I want to get the total amount of the area in a specific month.
I tried =SUMifs(Sheet2!H9:BZ379,Sheet2!H8:BZ8,E11,,Sheet2!F9:F,E12) I tried to use this function but I'm getting an error.
This is the sample spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sHaHWOo-h6SKubE4a_iA-d6L58KcKojLQe2xwd2tea8/edit?usp=sharing
Hope someone could help me out. Thanks in advance.

Make sure to provide input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Check my answer or other options to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

SUMIFS alone is not suitable if you have a different matrix of data. I would recommend that you try this Google Sheets formula. It first gets the match of the location and its corresponding values of every month, then sums the values based on your criteria.
Formula:
=LET(x, CHOOSECOLS(Sheet2!A8:BZ,{6,MATCH(E11,Sheet2!8:8,0)}), SUM(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(x, CHOOSECOLS(x,1) = E12),2)))

References:

Filter
Match
Choosecols
Let


Please do not hesitate to post a comment if you have any questions with regards to the answer above.

thank you very much.its working  well

Thank you for your kind response. If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvote the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. how to accept the answer.


Here's one approach you may test out:
=sumifs(let(Σ,substitute(address(1,xmatch(E11,Sheet2!8:8),4),1,),indirect("Sheet2!"&Σ&":"&Σ)), 
        Sheet2!F:F, E12)



thank you very much. i appreciate the help
